# Partial updates of objects

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

I want to enable update functionality for my `User` object in my fiber/gorm backend. It works fine when I update all fields together using the `Save` function. However, when I do not have all fields present in the update request (for example only the `Birthday` field but not the `Phone` field) it overwrites the rest of the fields with their respective null values.

```
func UserUpdateByID(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.DBConn

    // Parse the body to fit user entity
    user := entities.User{}
    if err := c.BodyParser(&user); err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).SendString(err.Error())
    }

    // Update record
    record := db.Save(&user)
    if record.Error != nil {
        return c.Status(500).SendString(record.Error.Error())
    }
return c.JSON(record.Value)
```

When I change the line with `record := db.Save(&user)` to

```
mappedData, _ := StructToMap(user)
record := db.Model(&entities.User{}).Update(mappedData)
```

I receive the error that `Update` can not handle map of interfaces: `sql: converting argument $10 type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map`

**Update 1:**
The mentioned StructToMap function looks like this:

```
func StructToMap(obj interface{}) (newMap map[string]interface{}, err error) {
    data, err := json.Marshal(obj)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &newMap) // Convert to a map
    return
}
```

**Update 2:**
The User object looks like:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Identity  string
  Birthday time.Time
  Phone string
  City string
  ...
  ActivityData         []Activity
}
```

Comment: What does the definition of `User` look like?

Comment: @hobbs added the User object in the question

Comment: Is there a better way of updating just a couple fields depending on the body of the request? I just saw that the c.BodyParser creates all the fields, even if they do not have data in the request.

Answer (score 2):

Looking, on gorm doc(https://gorm.io/docs/update.html), you can do something like this :
Use the **Updates** instead of **Update.**

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18, Active: false})
```

You can also use a **db.Debug**, to show the final query that gorm made, and see if matches with what are you expecting.

Comment: worth mentioning also, single column update `db.Model(&user).Update("name", "hello")`, and multi columns update via `map[string]interface{}`, ie, `db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"name": "hello", "age": 18, "active": false})`

Comment: Is this the only way to perform partial updates of objects in golang? Programmatically check every field in the update request object to see if it's zero and do not add it to the database update command?